# How to dynamically change filename in SQL Server Reporting Services when exporting to Excel

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I used SQL Server Reporting Services to export Excel file attached to an Email, I want to dynamically change the file name as current date (ex:20190422.xlsx).
How can I do that？

Comment: Do you have enterprise? If so, use Data Driven Subscriptions. If not, the task is much harder. Have a search for Data Driven Subscriptions in Standard Edition and let us know how you get on.

Comment: Round about way... you could run the report in SSRS and save it as a file. Then use a SQL Agent job to rename the file and email. I know... more chances of failure when done in separate steps.